# Connecting to external mysql DB (non localhost) using MAMP

Tags: mysql, database, mamp

Please keep in mind I'm a newbie to this.  I am editing php code using MAMP.  I do have an external host with FatCow and have set up a Database there.  I've been told to test on a localhost before posting to actual web host so I have my files stored in htdocs folder in MAMP and would like to create a connection to my external database.  Does MAMP only support localhost connection or can what I need be done?  Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just go ahead and try. It's the best method to check, don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

```
$con = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die("cannot connect to host");

Mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);
```

$host is the hostname given from your db hosting (IP address or domain name)

$user and $pass is your database user and password

$dbname is your database name..

If it doesn't output anything, then you've successfully connect to database...

Hope helps^^